# Print Function not working correctly in Chrome

Tags: javascript, php

I am using `windows.print();` for print specific part on web page, its working on firefox browser but not working correctly in Chrome

Comment: Do you mean `window.print();`?

Comment: What exactly not working not working correctly?

Comment: Its working on Firefox browser, but not Working correctly in Google Chrome, now get it??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`windows` is not any object in the javascript.

It is `window` so use the

```
window.print();
```

this will work. `window` is the object in Javascript.

Comment: @AasimGoriya mozilla browser ignores the global objects and read the function that's why. so use the window.

Comment: ohh its spell mistake, I use window and its working...thnks @Broken Heart